# Why this modified assembly does not run? (JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.)

Tags: bytecode, .net-assembly, il

I've modified the bytecode of an assembly to get rid off of an error and now when I try to use it I get a InvalidProgramException.
All I've done is replace this code with NOPS:

```
catch (Exception exception1)
{
    Exception exception = exception1;
    if (exception as InvalidValueException == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidGenerationException(2);
    }
    else
    {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

IL before:

```
catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
{
    IL_022f: stloc.s exception
    IL_0231: ldloc.s exception
    IL_0233: isinst Custom.InvalidValueException
    IL_0238: brfalse.s IL_023d

    IL_023a: ldloc.s exception
    IL_023c: throw

    IL_023d: ldc.i4.1
    IL_023e: newobj instance void Custom.InvalidGenerationException ...
    IL_0243: throw
}
```

IL after:

```
catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
{
    IL_022f: nop
    IL_0230: nop
    IL_0231: nop
    IL_0232: nop
    IL_0233: nop
    IL_0234: nop
    IL_0235: nop
    IL_0236: nop
    IL_0237: nop
    IL_0238: nop
    IL_0239: nop
    IL_023a: nop
    IL_023b: nop
    IL_023c: nop
    IL_023d: nop
    IL_023e: nop
    IL_023f: nop
    IL_0240: nop
    IL_0241: nop
    IL_0242: nop
    IL_0243: nop
}
```

Any ideas about why is this wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove all the nops?

Comment: I cannot change the length of the assembly with the utils I currently have, and normally is not a good idea (not sure if IL has jumps of this kind of things)

Comment: Why is it that you cannot simply handle the exception? Swallowing an exception is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Because is not my code, is a 3rd party assembly with a defect and its the 3rd party itself the one that its handling the exception when it shouldn't. I'm fixing the issue while waiting for a new version of the 3rd party that will take for sure some time.

Comment: I see. Is IL_0243 the last IL location?

Comment: The last location of the method? No, it isn't, the method continues after this code.

Comment: Protip: Always use `PEVerify` after running `ilasm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original `catch` block will always throw. That is, there's no way to exit the block "normally".

Your modified `catch` block doesn't throw so you need to exit the block normally. You'll need to use [`leave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.leave) or [`leave.s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.leave_s) to do that.

(You might also need to [`pop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.pop) the caught exception off the stack to keep things tidy. I'm not sure about that one though, you'll have to try it and see for yourself.)

```
catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
{
    IL_022f: pop                // not certain if pop is necessary
    IL_0230: leave.s IL_0244
    IL_0232: nop
    IL_0233: nop
    IL_0234: nop
    IL_0235: nop
    IL_0236: nop
    IL_0237: nop
    IL_0238: nop
    IL_0239: nop
    IL_023a: nop
    IL_023b: nop
    IL_023c: nop
    IL_023d: nop
    IL_023e: nop
    IL_023f: nop
    IL_0240: nop
    IL_0241: nop
    IL_0242: nop
    IL_0243: nop
}
IL_0244: ret    // or whatever
```

Comment: The leave instruction empties the evaluation stack so looks like the pop is not needed. Thanks!

Comment: @SoMoS: I had a feeling that might be the case, but wasn't 100% certain and didn't have time to check.

Comment: yeah, I know, I just put the comment for future references. Thanks again.